# Find the median of a function of a normal random variable.

Tags: probability, statistics, moment-generating-functions

If $X\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ and $Y=e^X$, then what is the median of $Y$?

I am pretty sure that $Y$ is also distributed normal.  To try to prove it, I attempted both the method of moment generating functions and the method of cdfs.  I just can't get it.  Thanks for your help.   Once I show that, getting the median is the same as getting the mean.

Comment: "I am pretty sure that Y is also distributed normal." Ouch! That hurts... Note that Y is always nonnegative.

Comment: Dag nabbit, this is why I should never graph functions of pdfs in my TI-84

Comment: If half the mass of $X$ is below $\mu$, then half the mass of $e^X$ is below $e^\mu$.

Comment: Some comments in this thread are now deleted, which originated from the OP's comment that "this is why (they) should never graph functions of pdfs in my TI-84". These were underlining the intrinsic uselessness of graph calculators to approach a whole class of mathematical questions, to which the present one belongs. As such, I cannot fathom why one saw fit to delete these comments (especially in view of how fiercely the OP resisted to the point explained to them and how widespread the misconceptions the exchange revealed are).

Answer (score 2):

Hint: let $\Phi$ be the CDF of $Z \sim \mathcal{N}\left(0, 1\right)$. Notice that
$$\mathbb{P}\left(Y \leq y\right) = \mathbb{P}\left(e^{X} \leq y\right) = \mathbb{P}\left(X \leq \ln(y)\right) = \mathbb{P}\left(Z \leq \dfrac{\ln(y)-\mu}{\sigma}\right)= \Phi\left[\dfrac{\ln(y)-\mu}{\sigma}\right]\text{.}$$

Comment: Thanks for that.  I got as far as that but then I didn't know how to continue.

Comment: Suppose $y$ is the median. What would the above equation have to be equal to?

Comment: $\phi\left[\frac{\ln(\mu)-\mu}{\sigma}\right]$

Comment: Nope. What is the definition of median?

Comment: wait no, because $Z$ is standard.

Comment: Oh well if $y$ was the median, then $P(Y\leq y)=1/2$.

Comment: Precisely. So set the above equation equal to $1/2$ and solve for $y$. The next step you need to take is the hard part, then it's just algebra from here. As a hint, what value $\cdot$ satisfies $\Phi(\cdot) = 1/2$?

Comment: Well since $\phi$ is the cdf of $Z$, then would the value you asked for be $0$?  Since $Z$ is normal?

Comment: Yep. Then it's just algebra from here. Just so you know, $Y$ does not follow a normal distribution, but rather, a *lognormal* distribution. It's just easy algebra from here, so I don't think we need to chat.

Comment: If the value IS 0, then $ln(y)=\mu$ and therefore $y=e^\mu$.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution#Mode_and_median

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

- What is a median of $X$ normal $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$?
- If $m$ is a median of the random variable $U$, and $V=A(U)$ where the function $A:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is nondecreasing, what would be a median of $V$?

Comment: The median is the value at which probabilities are 1/2 total on each side.  For your second question, I don't know.  I was tempted to say it should be the same since the pdf of $X$ is symmetrical about the $y$ axis.

Comment: This answers none of the two points.

Comment: You just changed your two points!  The answer to your new first point is $\mu$, again I don't know about the second point.

Comment: Not changed, paraphrased, to force you to read them.